# php spellcheck iteration optimization

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, iteration, spell-checking

Having recently begun working on a project which might need (good) scaling possibilities, I've come up with the following question:

Not taking into account the levensthein algorithm (I'm working with/on different variations), I iterate through each dictionary word and calculate the levensthein distance between the dictionary word and each of the words in my input string. Something along the lines of:

```
<?php
$input_words = array("this", "is", "a", "test");
foreach ($dictionary_words as $dictionary_word) {
    foreach ($input_words as $input_word) {
        $ld = levenshtein($input_word, $accepted_word);
        if ($ld < $distances[$input_word] || $distances[$word] == NULL) {
            $distances[$input_word] = $ld;
            if ($ld == 0)
                continue;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My question is on best practise: Execution time is ~1-2 seconds.
I'm thinking of running a "dictionary server" which, upon startup, loads the dictionary words into memory and then iterates as part of the spell check (as described above) when a request is recieved. Will this decrease exec time or is the slow part the iteration (for loops)? If so, is there anything I can do to optimize properly?

Google's "Did you mean: ?" doesn't take several seconds to check the same input string ;)

Thanks in advance, and happy New Year.

Comment: Since you mentioned google http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=526503

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read Norvig's [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html). Although the article uses Python, others have implemented it in PHP [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4859-PHP-Suggest-corrected-spelling-text-in-pure-PHP.html) and [here](http://soundofemotion.com/spellcorrect.txt).

Comment: At the bottom of it there are 2 links to 2 PHP-implementations

Comment: i managed to get an exec time of 0.0001-0.001 per word, by taking Norvig's example, tweaking a bit and leaving the initialization to the startup (running the python script as a server taking spelling questions and answering with the corrected version), so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You'd do well to implement your Dictionary as a Binary Tree or another more efficient data-structure.  The tree will reduce lookup times enormously.